# matcher.find() returning false while it should return true

Tags: java, regex

**I have to parse following type of strings with the `regex`:**

```
(alphanumeric word having 3 letters)(hyphen)(alphabetical word having 2 letters)(hyphen)(digits[minimum 1 digit])
```

**I have written following code for it:**

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("/([A-Z0-9]){1,3}(-)([A-Z]){2}(-)([0-9]){1,}/");
Matcher m = p.matcher("AB3-EF-52825");
System.out.println("matched or not>"+m.find());
```

I have made regex using http://regexr.com/. [image]

Ideally `m.find()` should print `true` as string suffices the regex but some how its printing `false`. I am not getting what is the issue!! Thanks!

Comment: Try matcher.matches();

Comment: @WeareBorg: I have tried it but not working. also, tried with matcher.lookingAt().

Comment: Remove "/.. /" (slash)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The forward slashes surrounding your `Pattern` are interpreted as literal slashes.

Remove those.

Also, never trust online websites, test and debug with Java.

Your working `Pattern`:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([A-Z0-9]){1,3}(-)([A-Z]){2}(-)([0-9]){1,}");
```

**Note**

Each item between parenthesis is assigned a group, for back-reference.

You may not need all items to be grouped, if you don't retrieve the back-references for them:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[A-Z0-9]{1,3}-[A-Z]{2}-[0-9]{1,}");
```

Answer (score 5):

You don't need regex delimiters in Java. Use:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([A-Z0-9]){1,3}-([A-Z]){2}-([0-9])+");
```

instead of:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("/([A-Z0-9]){1,3}(-)([A-Z]){2}(-)([0-9]){1,}/");
```

Comment: Yes that's true, lots of redundant groups.

Answer (score 3):

Just remove `/` from the beginning and the end of the pattern. This is used in PHP, Perl and Unix but not in Java.

Using

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([A-Z0-9]){1,3}(-)([A-Z]){2}(-)([0-9]){1,}");
```

works.

[This website works for Java regexes](http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html)

Comment: LOL, met the same problem coming from Node.js